# jQuery Print Preview Plugin not working with <h:commandLink>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2, jquery-plugins, print-preview

I am trying to use  [jQuery Print Preview Plugin](https://github.com/etimbo/jquery-print-preview-plugin) to show the prieview of a JSF page before printing it.

First I tried a demo with plain `HTML` tags.

```
<script src="../js/jquery.print-preview.js" type="text/javascript"
                    charset="utf-8"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

                    $j(function() {
                                alert("hai");
                                /*
                                 * Initialise print preview plugin
                                 */
                                 $j('.print-preview').printPreview();
                                 alert("bye");

                            });
                </script>

                <div id="header" class="container_12">
                     <a class="print-preview">Print this Page</a>
                </div>
```

I works correctly and the print -preview modal dailog is opened.

However,when i try replacing the `<a>` tag with `<h:commandLink>` the `$(this).bind('click', function(e)` within the `print-preview.js` is not triggered.

```
<h:form id="printForm">
                <script src="../js/jquery.print-preview.js" type="text/javascript"
                    charset="utf-8"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

                    $j(function() {
                                alert("hai");
                                /*
                                 * Initialise print preview plugin
                                 */
                                 $j('.print-preview').printPreview();
                                 alert("bye");

                            });
                </script>

                <div id="header" class="container_12">
                <h:commandLink id="sample" value="Print this page" styleClass="print-preview"/> 

                </div> 
</h:form>
```

I even tried using `$j('printForm\\:sample').printPreview();`, but still it is not working.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: do you have an error in the js console? have you tried to replace `<script>` by `<h:outputScript>`?

Comment: @Jini Samuel......First thing, is your script loading into your app? Did you check your server console? And Did you see any errors in browser console?

Comment: Yes, the script is loading into the app. I checked the scripts panel in my browser and it is showing the specific `print-preview.js` file. Also, there is no error in the error console. In fact, everything worked fine with the <a> tag. I just changed to <h:commandLink>. I was using the same <h:form> tag ,the <script> tag and the same XHTML page when  I used the <a> tag.

Comment: @JiniSamuel....`I even tried using $j('printForm\\:sample').printPreview();`. Is it formal mistake or real mistake on the page. it should be `$j('#printForm\\:sample')`

Comment: @SRy.... `$j('printForm\\:sample').printPreview();` was a mistake while asking the question.
Secondly, I replaced `<h:commmandLink>` with `<p:commandLink>` and everything works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced `<h:commandLink>` with `<p:commandLink>` and the  jQuery Print Preview Plugin works perfectly fine now.